# want to redirect a URL on the basis of #something

Tags: url, redirect

I want to set up something so that http://somedomain.com#specificdirectory

go straight to a specific directory.

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are seeking a server-side solution, you should know that the fragment identifier (that is, the URL part after #) is not regularly sent with the HTTP request, so your server cannot differentiate between http://somedomain.com#specificdirectory and http://somedomain.com -- it simply does not receive #specificdirectory. In case you cannot rely on a HTTP client to rewrite the fragment (e.g. from JavaScript) to a form that can be passed to your server, it is not possible to set up such redirection.